# Access methods from derived class using an object from base class

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, methods

I need to solve this problem about classes in C++. The problem says I need to create a base class, which has to be derived into 3 other derived classes. On main, I created a vector that can save objects from the base class to save the 3 different derived classes. The thing is that I don't know how to access the methods of the derivative classes when I access the vectors. For example, class C has 2 attributes and methods that base and other classes don't have, I need to have some way to access those methods using the vector of the base class. I hope someone could help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Base{
protected:
    string placa;
    int ano_de_registro;
public:
    Base(){};
    Base(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro):placa(_placa),ano_de_registro(_ano_de_registro){};

    const string &getPlaca() const {
        return placa;
    }

    int getAnoDeRegistro() const {
        return ano_de_registro;
    }

};

class A: public Base{
    int cubicaje;
    int caballos_de_fuerza;
    int contaminacion;//0==minimo, 1==normal y 2==excesivo

public:
    A(){};
    A(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro, int _cubicaje, int _caballos_de_fuerza, int _contaminacion):Base(_placa,_ano_de_registro),cubicaje(_cubicaje),caballos_de_fuerza(_caballos_de_fuerza),contaminacion(_contaminacion){};

    int getCubicaje()  {
        return cubicaje;
    }

    int getCaballosDeFuerza()  {
        return caballos_de_fuerza;
    }

    int getContaminacion()  {
        return contaminacion;
    }

};

class B: public Base{
    int cubicaje;
public:
    B(){};
    B(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro, int _cubicaje):Base(_placa,_ano_de_registro),cubicaje(_cubicaje){};

    int getCubicaje() const {
        return cubicaje;
    }
};


class C: public Base{
    int cantidad_de_ejes;
    int sobregarga;
public:
    C(){};
    C(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro,int _cantidad_de_ejes, int _sobregarga):C(_placa,_ano_de_registro),cantidad_de_ejes(_cantidad_de_ejes),sobregarga(_sobregarga){};

    int getCantidadDeEjes() {
        return cantidad_de_ejes;
    }

**    int getSobregarga() const {
        return sobregarga;
    }**
};


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a1,c1,c2,sc,cb,ct,cde, r1, vs;
    vector<string> Placas={"A1R 112","F5U-597","A1A-004","D5B-193","EUA-123","A8D-457","FCD-784","F0X-694","SLA-249","EBD-608",};
    vector<Base*> Vehiculos;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        r1=rand()%3;
        vs=rand()%Placas.size();
        a1=rand()%22+2000;
        c1=rand()%10;
        c2=rand()%10;
        cb=rand()%10;
        ct=rand()%3;
        cde=rand()%4+3;
        sc=rand()%10;
        A* carro=new A(Placas.at(vs),a1,c1,cb,ct);
        Vehiculos.push_back(carro);
    
        B* moto=new B(Placas.at(vs),a1,c2);
        Vehiculos.push_back(moto);

**        C* camion=new C(Placas.at(vs),a1,cde,sc);
        Vehiculos.push_back(camion);**
    }

    **Vehiculos.at(0)->getSobrecarga;**
    return 0;
}
```

Bold parts are the vector trying to access that method, the method itself and how I create the object using dynamic objects

Comment: You could use [virtual methods](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/virtual-functions).

Comment: `C(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro,int _cantidad_de_ejes, int _sobregarga):C(_placa,_ano_de_registro),cantidad_de_ejes(_cantidad_de_ejes),sobregarga(_sobregarga){};` looks like you want to construct the base class, not delegate to a non-existent  `C` constructor.

Comment: Vehiculos.at(0) has a a pointer to object A underlying not C. And object of class A doesn't have getSobrecarga. So you can't do that. But you can do that on Vehiculos.at(2)

Answer (score 0):

Note: it is usually better to expand the base class with `virtual` functions  so that no one needs to know exactly what type is being referenced. If the children are so different that a common interface is not possible, inheritance is probably not the right solution.

If you're being forced to do this for a course, there are two changes you need to make. The base class needs to have virtual methods to be polymorphic. It just so happens it needs a `virtual` destructor in order for the derived classes to be destroyed correctly from a reference to `Base`.

```cpp
class Base
{
protected:
    string placa;
    int ano_de_registro;
public:
    Base()
    {
    }
    
    Base(string _placa, int _ano_de_registro) :
            placa(_placa), ano_de_registro(_ano_de_registro)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default; //Addition

    const string& getPlaca() const
    {
        return placa;
    }

    int getAnoDeRegistro() const
    {
        return ano_de_registro;
    }

};
```

The second change is using [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

```cpp
    Vehiculos.at(0)->getSobrecarga;
```

becomes (I've also corrected a few omissions)

```cpp
    C* example = dynamic_cast<C*>(Vehiculos.at(2)); // get a C from the vector
    if (example) // test for non-null to make sure we did indeed get a C
    {
        example->getSobregarga(); // do the deed.
    }
```